# Unable to implement smooth scrolling using Jquery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Guys I am trying to implement smooth scrolling functionality on my webpage with the help of JQuery.

Whenever I click on the nav-item the page should be scrolled to the particular section. But That is not happening.

Here is my index.js code

```
$("#navbar a, .btn").on("click", function (event) {
  if (this.hash != "") {
    event.preventDefault();
    const hash = this.hash;

    $("html", "body").animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 100,
      },
      800
    );
  }
});
```

here is the link to the website try clicking on any of the nav-items and see.
https://umakanth-pendyala.github.io/Edge-Ledger/

Here is the link to my repo
https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/Edge-Ledger.git

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I can't get it to scroll at all, but I think you need to add "px" to your scrollTop value

Comment: Typo. `$('html', 'body')` should be `$('html, body')`, or just `$('html')`

Comment: Yep, It's the typo just as you mentioned in the second comment, Thank you for the help. Now It's working perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to required elements, here I've considered all the buttons with 
  //class name 'button'
  $(".button").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Or alternatively, add smooth scroll behavior to the entire document.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get it to behave smoothly is to set the milliseconds to be 0 instead of 800 and add the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` property to the `html` tag.

```
html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
```